# find the pypdfocr config.yaml file

Tags: python, python-2.7, tesseract, pdfkit, pypdf

Where can I locate the config.yaml file for pypdfocr?

In the [pypdfocr release info](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypdfocr), it mentions a config file I can use to specify where the OCR'ed documents are filed.

For example: `pypdfocr filename.pdf -f -c config.yaml` where the config.yaml file is like this:

```
target_folder: "docs/filed"
default_folder: "docs/filed/manual_sort"
original_move_folder: "docs/originals"

folders:
    finances:
        - american express
        - chase card
        - internal revenue service
    travel:
        - boarding pass
        - airlines
        - expedia
        - orbitz
    receipts:
        - receipt
```

The problem is, I don't know where this file is so I can customize to my own situation. Any ideas? On a Mac 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a full path to it when you pass it as the parameter, or start pypdfocr in the location as your config.yaml file.